# Meaning of “threw me off”

Tags: sentence-construction

In the book “Captivated by you”, the sentence read as follows

> His face brewed an evil storm. He pulled me up close and glared at me.
>   His foul breath **threw me off**. His touch sent a wave of revulsion
>   throughout my body.

What does **threw me off** here mean?

Answer (score 1):

When you are **thrown off**, you are momentarily disoriented. You can forget what you had intended to do or to say.

P.S.

There is a commonly used figure-of-speech:

> A storm was brewing.

It plays on the idea that the sky gets darker as a storm grows as tea, for example, gets darker as it is brewing.

We do not normally use the verb transitively when speaking of storms, but the author has taken some liberties there. The author might have said "An evil storm was brewing on his face".  Instead he expresses the idea transitively, making "face" the subject of the verb.

Comment: And can you please explain “his face brewed mean” is it his face became?

Comment: Please see the P.S.